# Does Maru support only path params and not query params?

Tags: rest, elixir, maru

I was getting me feet wet with `elixir` and decided to use [Maru](https://github.com/falood/maru) as the RESTful framework. I went through the [docs](https://maru.readme.io/docs) and googled for a day but could not find any documentation or examples on how to parse query params.

I want something like this

```
http://localhost:8080/app/rest/system/users?variable1=value1&variable2=value2
```

I want to parse the above url and populate a map with the query params `variable1` and `variable2`. Does Maru support this kind of operation?

Comment: It looks like the things defined in `params do ... end` _are_ query params. `route_param` defines path params. What code did you try that didn't work?

Comment: `params do ... end` is to get params from the request body.

Comment: Ah, got it. Do you also want the various validations to work with query params like they do with the request body params, or do you just want to access the raw query params from the current conn?

Comment: Just accessing the raw query params would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any functionality to do this in Maru's source code, but since Maru uses the `plug` package internally and allows full access to customizing the plug pipeline, you can plug in `Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params` and then access the params using `conn.params`:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Maru.Router
  plug :fetch_query_params

  get do
    json(conn, conn.params)
  end
end
```

```
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8800/?foo=bar&baz\[\]=quux'
{"foo":"bar","baz":["quux"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

At most time, this code help a lot, you can get all `path` `url` and `body` params.

Plug do it very well, so we shouldn't do it again.

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Maru.Router
  plug Plug.Parsers,
    pass: ["*/*"],
    json_decoder: Poison,
    parsers: [:urlencoded, :json, :multipart]

  get do
    json(conn, conn.params)
  end
end
```